# Koin library is not compile in Multiplatform project

Tags: android, kotlin, multiplatform, koin

I want to use koin library for DI in the Multiplatform project but I get some errors when I want to build the project. How can I fix them?

My Libraries:

```
object Koin {
    private const val version = "3.2.2"
    private const val koin_android_compose_version= "3.2.1"
    private const val koin_android_version= "3.2.2"

    const val koinCore = "io.insert-koin:koin-core:${version}"
    const val koinTest = "io.insert-koin:koin-test:${version}"
    const val koinAndroid = "io.insert-koin:koin-android:${version}"

    const val koinNavigation = "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-navigation:${koin_android_version}"
    const val koinWorkManager = "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-workmanager:$koin_android_version"
    const val koinCompose = "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose:$koin_android_compose_version"

    const val koinJUnit4= "io.insert-koin:koin-test-junit4:$version"
}
```

My android gradle:

```
with(Koin) {
        implementation(koinCore)
        testImplementation(koinTest)
        testImplementation(koinJUnit4)
        implementation(koinAndroid)
        implementation(koinNavigation)
        implementation(koinWorkManager)
        implementation(koinCompose)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

I have to exclude two libraries that the error told:

```
  implementation(koinAndroid){
            exclude("androidx.lifecycle", "lifecycle-viewmodel")
            exclude("androidx.lifecycle", "lifecycle-livedata-core")
        }

   implementation(koinWorkManager){
            exclude("androidx.lifecycle", "lifecycle-viewmodel")
            exclude("androidx.lifecycle", "lifecycle-livedata-core")
        }
```

All koin dependenscies:

```
 with(Koin) {
        implementation(koinCore)
        testImplementation(koinTest)
        testImplementation(koinJUnit4)
        implementation(koinAndroid){
            exclude("androidx.lifecycle", "lifecycle-viewmodel")
            exclude("androidx.lifecycle", "lifecycle-livedata-core")
        }
        implementation(koinNavigation)
        implementation(koinWorkManager){
            exclude("androidx.lifecycle", "lifecycle-viewmodel")
            exclude("androidx.lifecycle", "lifecycle-livedata-core")
        }
        implementation(koinCompose)
    }
```